# Ionic 3 button ng controller

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to use `ion-button` to change a number variable and then print that variable in the `ion-title`, but the function is not even running. I need to do it through an ng controller. I was trying with `<button ion-button ng-click="GoPage()" id="b1">Next</button>` and GoPage() is:

```
GoPage(){
    ++this.position;
    console.log(this.position);
  }
```

position is already defined as number equal to 0

Comment: Ionic3 is an Angular 2+ framework. The `ng-click` directive is AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do (click) in your template. In Ionic 3+ you need to leverage output event binding to initiate action such as click:

```
<button ion-button (click)="GoPage()" id="b1">Next</button>
```

Now if you want it to update ion-label you should use extrapolation binding using brackets {{ }}:

```
<ion-label>{{ position }} </ion-label>
```

Feel free to check out Ionic team's reference app here:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/tree/v3

There are a lot of pages that you can check implementation that is "canonical".

Comment: Thanks. Why can't I use the ng-click?

Comment: That is AngularJS (aka 1.0) binding and nowadays in Angular 2+ you need to use the new approach